# output all data in one dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, output

I just finished reading data from a text file into a single dimension array. My "for" statement is not outputting the data from the array. I want to output the entire array just to verify that all the data is there. However when i output an individual cell, the data goes out to the screen. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  const int MAX_CELLS = 500;      
  int count = 0;         
  double Vehicles[MAX_CELLS];   
  ifstream vehicleFile;           
  char type; 
  string license; 
  double charge; 

  vehicleFile.open ("VEHICLE.txt");   

  if (!vehicleFile)            
     cout << "Error opening vehicle file " << endl;

     vehicleFile >> type >> license ;              // priming read


     while (vehicleFile) {                         // while the read was successful

          cout << count << " "  << license << endl;    // FOR DISPLAY ONLY

          vehicleFile >> Vehicles[count];              // read into array

          count++;                                     // increment count

          vehicleFile >> type >> license;              // read next line

     }   

    cout << showpoint << fixed << setprecision(2); 


    for ( count; count < MAX_CELLS; count++) {
          cout << "Array #" << count << "is: ";        // OUTPUT ARRAY 
          cout << Vehicles[count] << endl; 
    }


    cout << Vehicles[8];       // READS DATA IN CELL 


    vehicleFile.close(); 


    system ("pause"); 
    return 0;       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` needs to be reset like so:

```
for ( count = 0; count < MAX_CELLS; count++) {
      cout << "Array #" << count << "is: ";        // OUTPUT ARRAY 
      cout << Vehicles[count] << endl; 
}
```

In the previous loop you are incrementing `count` for each record so it will already be set to the index of the last record when it reaches the `for` loop. Although really what you want to do is use a new variable and only iterate `count` times:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < count ; ++i) {
      cout << "Array #" << i << "is: ";        // OUTPUT ARRAY 
      cout << Vehicles[i] << endl; 
}
```

You are also not checking `MAX_CELLS` when you are reading in your data. So if you file has more than `MAX_CELLS` data then you will have undefined behavior.

Comment: Shafik, Thanks for that response and that makes perfect sense. However, the program is crashing now for some reason.

Comment: You just answered my question! I posted it before I refreshed my screen. Thanks i really appreciate it!

Comment: @llSpectrell Be **very** cautious about checking against `count`. You already have a constant that determines the size of the array. That is the safest way to ensure you stay within the bounds of your array.

Comment: Mike I would agree with you, however when i check against my max cells, the program crashes, when i check against count, the program executes.

Answer (score 1):

`count` persists after the while loop so it will be the end value after your while loop is completed. Then when it enters the for loop it will start at that value:

Consider this:

```
int count = 0
while(count < 10)
    count++

std::cout << "count is: " << count << std::endl;

for (count; count < 15; count++)
   std::cout << "now count is: " << count << std::endl
```

your output will be:

```
count is: 10
now count is: 11
now count is: 12
now count is: 13
now count is: 14
now count is: 15
```

you need to reset your count in or before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you do not re-initialize `count` (`count = 0`).

To make life easier, and avoid these kinds of **logic errors**, try:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS; ++i ) {
    cout << "Array #" << i << "is: ";        // OUTPUT ARRAY 
    cout << Vehicles[i] << endl; 
}
```

Currently, it looks like `count` is already greater than or equal to `MAX_CELLS`.